Data for Raydium Pool Maker fees transaction level
I used to be a Uniswap LP and we used a subgraph from TheGraph to pull transaction level maker fees for our LP positions for various pools.
Is there anything like this for Raydium?  Clearly it is stored somewhere as it shows up in the UI layer on raydium.io but I haven't been able to find documenation
